# Behavior of scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

why the program is not stopping at the line 4 for taking the input?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a, b;
  char c1, c2;
  printf("Enter something: ");
  scanf("%d",&a); // line 1
  printf("Enter other something: ");
  scanf("%d", &b); // line 2

  printf("Enter a char: "); 
  scanf("%d",&c1); // line 3
  printf("Enter other char: ");
  scanf("%d", &c2); // line 4

  printf("Done"); // line 5

  system("PAUSE");  

  return 0;
}
```

i read this question from a book and in above line 4 the scanf() is not executing but why?

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’

Comment: Incase you would like to input `SPACE` as well while inputting data, you can try this as well :- `scanf("%[^\n]c",&c2);`
This will let you keep on inputting the data till there is space available assigned to the variable or till a `New Line` is not encountered.

Comment: Code using `"%d"` to read into a `char` at line `scanf("%d",&c1); // line 3` certainly would enlist a compiler warning.  The major problem here is not that code is messed up, but that compilers warnings are not enabled or adhered.  Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` expects to read a bunch of digits from input, so that it can form an integer and store the result into the pointer you pass (which is invalid in this example, since you provided a pointer to char, but anyway, this is irrelevant here).

The problem is that if you input a character, `scanf()` will notice that there isn't a valid digit on input. It will read this character, push it back into the input, and return prematurely. This happens on line 3. Since the character was pushed back, line 4 will again retrieve the same character from input and see that there is no valid integer on input, so the same character is pushed back again.

The key point to keep in mind here is that `scanf` returns prematurely with invalid input, leaving the input stream untouched.

For example, if `stdin` holds the character `a`, `scanf()` on line 3 will retrieve an `a` from input. It sees that this cannot be a valid digit, so `a` "goes back" to `stdin` and `scanf()` returns. On line 4, the `scanf` call will do the same thing: it picks the next item from input, which is the same `a`, and returns prematurely. **Scanning for integers won't work until you consume this character**. For example, if you call `getchar()` after line 3, you consumed the problematic character, and `scanf()` on line 4 will wait for input.

Comment: please elaborate the words you written in bold.thanks!

Comment: @Bayant_singh As long as you keep giving `%d` to `scanf()` when there's something that is not a digit on input, `scanf()` will *always* return prematurely. `scanf()` only consumes characters from `stdin` that it is supposed to consume. If you tell it to grab an integer and there are no digits on input, it will never consume any input. So the characters just lie there. You have to consume it yourself (with `getchar()` or `scanf()` with the right formatters) before trying to match an integer again.

Comment: Goncalves but when i changed the "%d" of last two statements to "%c" then the output is "Enter a char:Enter other char:" and here it stops at fourth scanf() instead of third,why so?

Comment: @Bayant_singh Because `%c` accepts ordinary characters. Thus it will consume any character on the input stream, **including spaces and newlines**. So, `scanf` on 3rd line is most likely consuming a newline or space from the previous input (`%d` doesn't consume trailing white spaces).

Comment: @Filipe_Goncalves ok sir...thanxx a lot.is stdin an input buffer?

Comment: @Bayant_singh Yes, `stdin` is buffered. But this is generally hidden from the user perspective.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` has issues with the newline. A quick and dirty way to solve this, is by adding a space or a `\n` before `%c` in order to bypass that...

```
  printf("Enter a char: "); 
  scanf(" %c",&c1); // line 3
  printf("Enter other char: ");
  scanf(" %c", &c2); // line 4
```

Comment: what will this space do?

Comment: It makes scan consume the newline character.

Comment: Scanf reads a newline character, which is left in the input buffer from by the previous call. Scanf is not robust.
The FreeBSD man pages scanf(3):
(http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3)
c  Matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no terminating NUL is added). The usual
skip of leading white space is suppressed. To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("Enter a char: "); 
  scanf("%c",&c1); // line 3
  printf("Enter other char: ");
  scanf("%c", &c2); // line 4
```

change %d with %c (from decimal to character)

Comment: `c1` will likely take on the value of `'\n'` left-over from the previous `scanf("%d", &b); // line 2`. `" %c"` is certainly more to the OP's need.